# is it possible to connect to sites over the internet

Tags: networking, vpn, site-to-site-vpn

I have two sites which are 3km away from each other, both sites have internet access from the same ISP. I would like both sites to have access to each other throught the internet routers (TP-Link TD-W8968). Is it possible?? if not, please explain what do I need to achieve the connection with the lowest cost possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use IPsec VPN to connect the two routers. You can do this directly between your current routers - no need to spend any money.

According to the [manual](https://static.tp-link.com/TD-W8968(EU)_V5_User_Guide_1481360123290w.pdf) these routers support up to 10 IPsec tunnels (you only need one). IPsec is fast and secure, and with the VPN running from edge to edge you have no NAT issues.

Refer to the linked pdf at page 61 for configuration instructions.

Comment: thank you, I will check this. I just started to go with the Dynamic DNS solution. If you can recommend a reliable provider if you know any, I will be thankful.

Comment: You may have issues with site to site VPN with dynamic IPs. I would actually recommend you talk to your ISP about getting static IPs for your two sites. It is usually very cheap and will be much simpler for you.

Comment: it is not cheap at all in here. It would cost me 100$ monthly. That's why I have been looking for alternative ways. as most Dynamic DNS providers provide the service with their own software to keep your external IP address updated to your hostname. I have already tried some free providers and its working well till now. am just wondering which one of them is reliable and trusted as there are too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like both sites to have access to each other throught the internet routers

Yes, this is called a VPN (Virtual Private Network). People have been doing this since the birth of the internet. There are a thousand different VPN solutions out there, but the common ones in use today are L2TP, IKEv2, IPSEC.

> P-Link TD-W8968

No idea, but routers that do site-to-site VPNs are plentiful so if your router doesn't do it, get one that does. It shouldn't cost much.

Comment: thank you, I had the site to site option on mind as someone offered me the solution from NE section just before redirecting me in here.  and I will have a look at IPSEC.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a Virtual Private Network (VPN) to achieve this. It's very very common and you will find a whole host of VPN providers, some expensive some cheap, that will be able to offer you a solution. Just do your research and see what suits you best.

Comment: I have been looking for hosts and found no-ip services, am just wondering if they require from me to have a static IP address from my ISP, because it is expensive in here. thanks for the response by the way.